# Is it possible to deprecate a sass/scss mixin?

Tags: sass

When maintaining and updating the mixins for a large team of developers, is it possible to deprecate mixins so that they throw some sort of warning when the styles are compiled?

I do not simply want to remove the deprecated mixins as it will take some time to remove all the current uses, but it'd be nice to warn the other developers that this is being removed if they attempt to use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `@warn` directive for this. From the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id9):

> The @warn directive prints the value of a SassScript expression to the standard error
>   output stream. It’s useful for libraries that need to warn users of deprecations or
>   recovering from minor mixin usage mistakes.

You'd use it like this:

```
@mixin old-mixin {
    @warn "This old mixin is deprecated!";

    // mixin definition here
}
```